# How do I show the full output for df.describe()?

Tags: python, dataframe, statistics, output

I'm using df.describe() to get a summary of my data, but I'm only able to see the first and last variables. I want to be able to see all the output from the code so that I can copy it into a word file. How am I able to do that?

[image: Screenshot of current output]

Comment: Be careful linking to off-site images (now resolved), as such posts sometimes garner the ire of some Stack users (not unfairly). Also, a lack of code will irk some people, so even just [creating a mock dataframe](https://feliperego.github.io/blog/2019/01/11/Creating-Fake-Mock-Data-Python) can sometimes help. I know it seems trivial, especially for easy questions but an early downvote can completely relegate a question to the graveyard, which can be a little disheartening.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`df.to_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html), for example:

```
df.to_csv(file_name, sep='\t', index = False)
```